# How to reuse block of HTML in template of component?

Tags: angular

I have some Angular components with the same HTML structure

```
<div class='something'>
 <div ...> 
    <custom HTML code for Component>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now, how can I reuse code to something like

```
<popup-template>
  <custom HTML code for Component>
</popup-template>
```

Comment: why did you remove answer? ng-content is not recomended when you think about reusability as your question says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is commonly called a "slot".
It's `<ng-content></ng-content>` in Angular.
Take a look at this article: https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b

Answer (score 0):

Make that custom HTML code as a component and you can use it anywhere in another component using the selector.

```
<popup-template>
  <custom-component></custom-component>
</popup-template>
```